# How to use log4net in MAUI

Tags: maui

MAUI is a new platform. I used log4net with worker service but doesn't know how to use with MAUI.

Can you supply full sample code how to use log4net with MAUI ?

Thanks in advance.

```html
public class AppLogManager { 
private static AppLogManager _logManager = null; 
public ILog _logger; 
private AppLogManager() 
{ }
 public AppLogManager(string fullConfigFilePath, Assembly assembly) 
{ 
var logRepo = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(assembly); log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepo, new FileInfo(fullConfigFilePath)); _logManager = new AppLogManager(); 
}

public static AppLogManager GetLogger<T>()
 { 
return _logManager.GetLogger(typeof(T)); 
} 
public AppLogManager GetLogger(Type type) 
{ 
_logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(type); 
return _logManager; 
} 
public void Info(string message)
 { 
_logger.Info(message); 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Log4net with MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451050/how-to-use-log4net-with-maui)

Comment: you already asked this and it was closed as off-topic.  Please to not post duplicate questions.  For guidance on writing an on-topic question, see [ask].